# How to check if rootViewController is of a specific class?

Tags: iphone, ios

I would like to know if the rootViewController in a navigation controller stack is of specific class. How to do such a thing ?

Thx for helping,

Stephane

Answer (score 11):

Here you go buddy

```
id rootController = [self.navigationController rootViewController];
if([rootController isKindOfClass:[YourDesiredController class]]){
  //do something
 }
```

Comment: There is no *property/method* named *rootViewController* in *UINavigationController*

Comment: so how do I get the rootViewController ?

Comment: By using `[[navigationController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
`.

Answer (score 2):

The navigation controllers root view controller is,

```
id rootVC = [[navigationController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
```

And check the *class* of *rootVC* like this,

```
if ([rootVC isKindOfClass:[YourClass class]]) {
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the class with:

```
if ([rootViewController isKindOfClass:[YourClass class]]){

}else if ([rootViewController isKindOfClass:[AnotherClass class]]){

}else{
}
```

Comment: how to get the rootViewController ?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can use the method isKindOfClass

```
[rootViewController isKindOfClass: [RootViewController class]];
```

Answer (score 0):

How to check your current `rootViewController` and use it in an `if statement` :

```
// Get your current rootViewController
NSLog(@"My current rootViewController is: %@", [[[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate.window.rootViewController class]);

// Use in an if statement
UIViewController *rootViewController = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate.window.rootViewController;
if ([rootViewController isKindOfClass:[MyViewController class]])
{
    NSLog(@"Your rootViewController is MyViewController!!");
}
```